# How do you override a setting in the root media folder of Joomla 2.x

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

Basically I have a module I installed, it is in the modules folders as well, but the css I need to change is in the media folder.  How to I override this, do I use the HTML folder in my template folder somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to have a specific CSS file in your template, with selectors that override the standard module CSS. Unfortunately, Joomla doesn't have a standard way of checking for template versions of module or component CSS, in the way it does for view files.

Use the CSS hierarchy to have your override CSS rules loaded AFTER the default module CSS rules, and they will take precedence. Make sure your override CSS file is the last one loaded by the template.

Comment: A separate css with over ride rules was the simplest solution, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

How is the original CSS file loaded? Does the module load it in its template file or someplace else? If it is loaded in the template, just override the template file and change the lines that load that file. If it's not loaded in the template, it is probably loaded just before rendering the template. In this case, the solution is also to override the template and load your own css file which will contain rules to override the ones in the original file. In this case, unfortunately, the original file will be loaded in addition to your css file. It amounts to an extra http request but it's probably not a big deal.